Unity, Fish-Net Synchronizing
I'm trying to make a 1v1 card game with Fish-net, I'm having a problem Synchronizing a variable of type int "Turn" and display for both players, I've already tried to do it but the variable isn't Synchronizing.
TurnButton script -
This script is attached to the "End Turn button", it is used to call the "EndOfTurn()" method of the GameManager script.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TurnButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerManager pm;

    public void EndTurn() {
    
        pm = FindObjectOfType<PlayerManager>();

        pm.playerObj.GetComponent<GameManager>().EndOfTurn();
    }

}

GameManager script - This script is attached to the player
I followed a tutorial on YouTube that did it this way but the problem is that the "Turn" variable does not increase the number and it does not want to set the "turnText" variable.
And when I click on the button to end the turn for player 2 this error appears - "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameManager.OnTurnChanged (System.Int32 oldTurn, System.Int32 newTurn, System.Boolean asServer) (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:32)"
public class GameManager : NetworkBehaviour {
    public BattleState battleState;
    public TMP_Text turnoText;
    public int turn = 1;
    public readonly SyncVar<int> _turn = new();
    
    void Awake() {
        _turn.OnChange += OnTurnChanged;
    }

    public void OnTurnChanged(int oldTurn, int newTurn, bool asServer) {
        newTurn += 1;
        turnoText.text = "Turno " + newTurn;
    }

    public void StartOfTurn() {
        if (coin >= coinMax) {
            coin = 10;
        } else {
            coin += 1;
        }

        coinText.text = coin.ToString();

        SetTurn(turn);

    }

    public void EndOfTurn() {
        if (battleState == BattleState.PLAYER1) {
            battleState = BattleState.PLAYER2;
        } else {
            battleState = BattleState.PLAYER1;

        }

        StartOfTurn();
    }

    [ServerRpc] private void SetTurn(int turn) => _turn.Value = turn;

I already tried to use this video as a reference "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir_TzuqYZxc&list=PLF6lFlLzb6CSuf4g8ZR1VRq-TAgC6AQWD&index=30", I already tried to use "SyncVar" but in the new versions they changed.
